There are some weird edges and shadows in final render Cycles
I'm using boolean modifier to create some holes and it works fine in eevee render and everything is smooth but in cycles I get some weird edges and shadows.



Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

It seemed it was a bug in blender 4.1 which was showing me no difference between shade smooth and shade auto smooth. these weird edges occurred because of shade smooth and blender 4.1 was showing me nothing in eevee only in cycles.
I accidentally switched to blender 4.0 and saw these both in eevee and cycles and fixed it.

